# Which code says the number of voice channels on the server?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a serverinfo command, but first I need to know which code says the number of voice channels on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of voice channels in a guild, you could do:

```js
const voiceChannelCount = message.guild.channels.filter(c => c.type === 'voice').size;
```

which will filter through all the channels, only get the voice channels, and get its size.

***Note:** I noticed you're a new member! First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Second of all, be sure to mark the answer of your questions by clicking the check next to the answer that helped you solve it so people know this question got it's answer and someone new can also find it easily!*

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get all the channels in the guild, then filter out the ones that are not voice channels.

```js
// let's say guild is the guild you're working with, and that it's already cached
guild
  .channels // Guild.channels
  .cache // GuildChannelManager.cache
  .filter(channel => channel.type == 'voice') // Collection.filter()
  .size // Map.size
```